# Use JavaScript to evaluate webMathematica tags?

Tags: webmathematica

In my HTML form I have 3 buttons. Each button calls different `.mx` files, based upon an `.mx file data`. `listplot` will be created in another `jsp` page. I placed all `.mx` files under `WEB-INF/Applications`.

I wrote 3 functions in Javascript. Inside these functions I wrote the *webMathematica* code between `<msp:evaluate>`tags. However the code doesn't seem to be working inside a Javascript function. I wrote the functions in the following way:

```javascript
function button1()
    {
        <msp:evaluate>
            Get["Data/first.mx"];
            mxData=first;
        </msp:evaluate>
        var id=document.getElementById("name");
        id.action="second.jsp";
        id.submit();
    }
```

I called this function in the following way:

```html
 <input type="button" value="Button1" onclick="button1()"/>
```

Comment: You have to use jQuery or Ajax or something like this. I have not done this and have no time right now, but please check out [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/596663/Struts/Calling-jsp-include-tag-javascript) and let us know if you get it working for MSP.